# Can't get expected result when I execute a succes query in JSP MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, resultset

I am trying to execute the next code. The query works well (or I think so), but I can't get theresult that I expect.

I have 3 documents.

**servlet.jsp:**

```
private void validate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String name, String password) 
        throws ServletException, IOException
{

    ResultSet resultat;
    resultat= UserDAO.validate(name, password);
    request.setAttribute("login",resultat);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");

    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
public static ResultSet validate(String name, String password) 
{
    int contador=0;
    Connection cn=null;
    ResultSet rst=null;
   try{
        //crear la connexion
        cn = ConnectionDB.getConection(); //tenemos que llamar a la connexion

        String selectSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM users WHERE name like ? AND password like ?";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = cn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" + name + "%");
        password=UserDAO.md5(password);//llamamos al método para encriptar
        preparedStatement.setString(2,"%" + password + "%");
        preparedStatement.execute();

   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
        rst=null;
        System.out.println("error while trying to validate a valid userD");
   }
   finally{  

   }
    return rst;
}
```

(*cn = ConnectionDB.getConection();* and  *password=UserDAO.md5(password);* ARE CORRECT)
-I have the User class with the correct getters, setters and constructor.

**And it finishes in index.jsp**

```
 if(request.getAttribute("login")!=null)
        {

            ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) request.getAttribute("login");

            if (!rs.next() ) 
          {
              out.println("Incorrect username or password. Try again");
          }

          else{
                rs.beforeFirst();
                out.println("CORRECT LOGIN");

               //response.sendRedirect("servletBook?validated");

          }

        }
```

I am expected to get the message "Incorrect username or password. Try again" or "CORRECT LOGIN", but, none of 2 appears on the screen. I can't understand why.

Comment: Do you get any errors/exceptions?

Comment: What is in your servlet's `do...()` methods?

Comment: I don't get any errors or exceptions. // The doGet and doPost are like netbeans creates it by default.